# Unnecessary white space on right and buttom of Angular app

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm pretty much new in web development so may be this one is a stupid question but I seriously need help over here. I've built my first angular app and on the landing page there seems to be plenty of white space on right, and also on the bottom after the footer when on mobile view. I've tried making the the components full viewpoint width but then the animation of the page is getting distorted and no matter what I do, the space after footer still remains. You can check my Github repository [here](https://github.com/tridibc2/projectv2.0.1). Below I'm attaching a screenshot and also my footer component code:
[image: hg]

footer.html:

```
<footer id="footer" class="footer-1 area">
  <div class="main-footer widgets-dark typo-light">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="widget subscribe no-box">
  <h5 class="widget-title"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="50" height="40" alt="LOGO" >WEBBNET DIGITAL<span></span></h5>
  <p>KOLKATA - 700064</p>
  </div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 footer-top">
  <div class="widget no-box">
  <h5 class="widget-title">Get Started<span></span></h5>
  <p>SEND IN A QUERY</p>
  <a class="btn" #myModal (click)="openModal()">Register Now</a>
  </div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 footer-top">
  <div class="widget no-box">
  <h5 class="widget-title">Contact Us<span></span></h5>
  <p><a href="mailto:" title="glorythemes">support</a></p>
  <ul class="social-footer2">
  <li class=""><a href="https://www.facebook.com/webbnetdigital/" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><img alt="Facebook" width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64></a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" title="Twitter"><img alt="Twitter" width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png></a></li>
  <li class=""><a title="instagram" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/webbnetdigital/"><img alt="instagram" width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;></a></li>
  <li class=""><a title="linkedin" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/webbnet-digital/"><img alt="linkedin" width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div><div class="footer-copyright"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <p>Copyright</p></div></div></div></div>
  <ul class="circles">
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></footer>
```

footer.css:

```
/* Main Footer */
footer .main-footer{    padding: 20px 0; z-index: 1;}
footer ul{  padding-left: 0;    list-style: none;}

/* Copy Right Footer */
.footer-copyright { background: #222;   padding: 5px 0;}
.footer-copyright .logo {    display: inherit;}
.footer-copyright nav {    float: right;    margin-top: 5px;}
.footer-copyright nav ul {  list-style: none;   margin: 0;  padding: 0;}
.footer-copyright nav ul li {   border-left: 1px solid #505050; display: inline-block;  line-height: 12px;  margin: 0;  padding: 0 8px;}
.footer-copyright nav ul li a{  color: #969696;}
.footer-copyright nav ul li:first-child {   border: medium none;    padding-left: 0;}
.footer-copyright p {   color: #969696; margin: 2px 0 0;}

/* Footer Top */
.footer-top{    padding-bottom: 30px;   margin-bottom: 30px;    border-bottom: 3px solid #222;}
/* Footer transparent */
footer.transparent .footer-top, footer.transparent .main-footer{    background: transparent;}
footer.transparent .footer-copyright{   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ;}
/* Footer light */
footer.light .footer-top{   background: #f9f9f9;}
footer.light .main-footer{  background: #f9f9f9;}
footer.light .footer-copyright{ background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) ;}
/* Footer 4 */
.footer- .logo {    display: inline-block;}
/*==================== 
    Widgets 
====================== */
.widget{    padding: 20px;  margin-bottom: 40px;}
.widget.widget-last{    margin-bottom: 0px;}
.widget.no-box{ padding: 0; background-color: transparent;  margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; -ms-box-shadow: none; -o-box-shadow: none;}
.widget.subscribe p{    margin-bottom: 18px;}
.widget li a{   color: #de6b28;}
.widget li a:hover{ color: #233B66;}
.widget-title {margin-bottom: 20px;}
.widget-title span {background: #839FAD none repeat scroll 0 0;display: block; height: 1px;margin-top: 25px;position: relative;width: 20%;}
.widget-title span::after {background: inherit;content: "";height: inherit;    position: absolute;top: -4px;width: 50%;}
.widget-title.text-center span,.widget-title.text-center span::after {margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto;left: 0;right: 0;}
.widget .badge{ float: right;   background: #7f7f7f;}

.typo-light h1, .typo-light h2, .typo-light h3, .typo-light h4, .typo-light h5, .typo-light h5,.typo-light p,.typo-light div,.typo-light span,.typo-light small{    color: #fff;}
.footer-top {
  margin-top: .5em;}
ul.social-footer2 { margin: 0;padding: 0;   width: auto;}
ul.social-footer2 li {display: inline-block;padding: 0;}
/* ul.social-footer2 li a:hover {background-color:#de6b28;} */
ul.social-footer2 li a {display: block; height:30px;width: 30px;text-align: center; z-index: 2;}
.btn{background-color: #de6b28; color:#fff; z-index: 2;}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus, .btn.active {background: #233B66;color: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-o-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 0s;}

/* Animations */
.area{
    background: #252525;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #de6b28, #de6b28);  
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

}

.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events:none;
    user-select: none;
    z-index:1}
.circles li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #de6b28;
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;

}
.circles li:nth-child(10){
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}


.circles li:nth-child(9){
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8){
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7){
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
}
.circles li:nth-child(6){
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.circles li:nth-child(5){
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.circles li:nth-child(4){
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}
.circles li:nth-child(3){
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
}
.circles li:nth-child(2){
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;}
.circles li:nth-child(1){left: 85%;width: 150px;height: 150px;animation-delay: 0s;animation-duration: 11s;}
@keyframes animate {
0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cloned your repo and found out that the `ul` element with the id `circles` is causing the white space problem.

Just add `margin: 0` to that element and the white space should disappear.